# Automaton for recognition abc , bac, bca .. words

Tags: python, algorithm, automation, permutation

I need to build an automation, to permutate letters of three symbols - a,b,c. For example the results can be - abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba, total 6 permutations for 3 symbols. Can this be coded in Python?

Please help! Each symbol can be used only one time. And length of each permutation must be equal to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest one is the following:

[image]

Comment: You can also merge leaves q10 and q12, leaves q11 and q14 and leaves q13 and q15 to get it with a little less states.